# Generate combinations of string elements in a list, limiting them to a particular character amount

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, combinations

I want to generate 5 combinations of the films beneath, limiting them to a particular character amount.

```
films = ['Pulp Fiction','The Lion King','Reservoir Dogs','The Wolf of Wall Street','Jackie Brown','The Shawshank Redemption','Django Unchained','The Godfather','Gone Girl','The Dark Knight']
```

I intend on having the character amount changeable (*let's say 50 characters for this example*).

*Intended result*:

```
for i in film_combinations_limited:
    i[0] = ['The Shawshank Redemption, The Wolf of Wall Street'] (49 characters inc comma)
    i[1] = ['Pulp Fiction, Gone Girl, The Wolf of Wall Street'] (48 characters inc comma)
    i[2] = ['Reservoir Dogs, Pulp Fiction, The Dark Knight'] (45 characters inc comma)
    i[3] = ['Jackie Brown, Django Unchained, Pulp Fiction'] (44 characters inc comma)
    i[4] = ['The Wolf of Wall Street, The Lion King'] (38 characters inc comma)
    i[5] = ['Pulp Fiction, The Shawshank Redemption'] (38 characters inc comma)
```

I wish to make full use of the character limit, **commas** and **spaces** also need to be considered in the character limit.

*Current code*:

```
import itertools

x_raw=[el.split(' ') for el in films] 
x=[el for sublist in x_raw for el in sublist] #Not sure if I understood, what do you mean by "substring" - these 2 lines will produce substring ~ word

n=50 # character limit

res=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
   for obj in itertools.combinations(x, i+1):
      res_temp = " ".join(obj)
      #to ensure total number of characters <25 but it's high enough, that no other word from lorem/x will fit
      if((len(res_temp) < n) and (n-len(res_temp)<=min([len(el) for el in [el_x for el_x in x if el_x not in obj]] or [100]))): res.append(res_temp)
```

This generates one combination instance without including the comma or space. I'm trying to achieve many outputs that fill the character limit as much as possible.

The output of this code doesn't matter and can change from being a list.

For any more information / clarification, please ask.

Thanks

Comment: Why so much complication about the spaces and commas?  I think you just need to iterate over all possible combinations, joine the full movie names (over `', '`) and check if the length is short enough.  Why this splitting over space etc.?

Comment: Do you want the _longest_ possible solutions?

Comment: @Alfe yes that's desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that, assuming that you are looking to have the longest ones selected:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

# Itertools recipe
def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def get_longest_combinations(names, num, max_length):
    # All combinations with their total length
    g = ((sum(map(len, c)) + 2 * len(c) - 1, c) for c in powerset(names))
    # Filter by total length and negate length for sorting
    g = ((s, c) for s, c in g if s <= max_length)
    # Pick longest ones
    longest = sorted(g)[:-num-1:-1]
    # Format
    return [', '.join(c) for _, c in longest]

films = ['Pulp Fiction', 'The Lion King', 'Reservoir Dogs', 'The Wolf of Wall Street',
         'Jackie Brown', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'Django Unchained', 'The Godfather',
         'Gone Girl', 'The Dark Knight']
n = 50
m = 5
result = get_longest_combinations(films, m, n)
print(*result, sep='\n')
# The Wolf of Wall Street, The Shawshank Redemption
# The Wolf of Wall Street, The Godfather, Gone Girl
# The Lion King, The Wolf of Wall Street, Gone Girl
# Reservoir Dogs, Django Unchained, The Dark Knight
# Pulp Fiction, The Shawshank Redemption, Gone Girl
```

You can make this line:

```
longest = sorted(g)[-num:]
```

Faster if you use a heap to pick the longest elements:

```
import heapq

def max_n(it, n):
    it = iter(it)
    h = [next(it)]
    for elem in it:
        if len(h) < n:
            heapq.heappush(h, elem)
        elif elem > h[0]:
            heapq.heappop(h)
            heapq.heappush(h, elem)
    return sorted(h, reverse=True)

# ...
longest = max_n(g, num)
```

---

If the size of the number of names is long, the size of the power set (2<sup>n</sup>) will be too big. You cannot really "fix" that issue if you want to get the best combinations, but you can reduce the search space a bit if you stop exploring at partial combinations that cannot be successful. You can do that with a recursive algorithm like this:

```
import heapq

def get_longest_combinations(names, num, max_length):
    h = []
    _get_longest_combinations_rec(names, num, max_length, h, [], -2, 0)
    return [', '.join(c) for _, c in sorted(h, reverse=True)]

def _get_longest_combinations_rec(names, num, max_length, h, cur, cur_size, name_idx):
    if h and cur_size > h[0][0]:
        heapq.heappop(h)
    if len(h) < num:
        heapq.heappush(h, (cur_size, tuple(cur)))
    cur_size += 2
    for i in range(name_idx, len(names)):
        name = names[i]
        cur.append(name)
        cur_size += len(name)
        if cur_size < max_length:
            _get_longest_combinations_rec(
                names, num, max_length, h, cur, cur_size, i + 1)
        cur_size -= len(name)
        cur.pop()

films = ['Pulp Fiction', 'The Lion King', 'Reservoir Dogs', 'The Wolf of Wall Street',
         'Jackie Brown', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'Django Unchained', 'The Godfather',
         'Gone Girl', 'The Dark Knight']
n = 50
m = 5
result = get_longest_combinations(films, m, n)
print(*result, sep='\n')
# The Wolf of Wall Street, The Shawshank Redemption
# The Wolf of Wall Street, The Godfather, Gone Girl
# The Lion King, The Wolf of Wall Street, Gone Girl
# Reservoir Dogs, Django Unchained, The Dark Knight
# Pulp Fiction, The Shawshank Redemption, Gone Girl
```

Comment: @jdehesa how can I pass a list to this function? if the films list is outside of the func

Comment: @GJB I have rewritten it as a function, see if that helps. Also a minor fix.

Comment: @Alfe Yes `return sorted(h, reverse=True)` could be replaced by `heapq.nlargest(len(h), h)` if preferred.

Comment: This solution also tries all combination with five movie names, even if all combinations with four movie names were too long already.  This is no problem in this case but it sure will be a massive (and easily avoidable) problem if you have a longer list of movies.  With a thousand movies this solution will not terminate within a reasonable time.

Comment: @Alfe Yes, your solution optimizes that a bit, although it could prune more cases, e.g. if `A, B` is already too long, I shouldn't try `A, B, C`, `A, B, C, D`, etc. I added a recursive algorithm for that.

Comment: I only wanted to make sure that with a thousand movie names it still terminates in acceptable time.  ABCD is only tested if a combination of three others was short enough.  But you are right, there might be edge cases in which my solution still wastes significantly more time than yours needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution overcomplicates the thing.  There is no need to split the movie names by spaces etc.

```
import itertools

films = ['Pulp Fiction','The Lion King','Reservoir Dogs',
         'The Wolf of Wall Street','Jackie Brown','The Shawshank Redemption',
         'Django Unchained','The Godfather','Gone Girl','The Dark Knight']

def each_short_combination(films, max_length=50):
  for i in range(len(films)):
    yielded_something = False
    for combination in itertools.combinations(films, i):
      output = ', '.join(combination)
      if len(output) < max_length:
        yield output
        yielded_something = True
    if not yielded_something:  # nothing yielded with i movie names?
      break  # no need to try longer combinations then

answers = list(each_short_combination(films))
answers.sort(key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
answers = answers[:5]

for answer in answers:
  print(answer, len(answer))
```

This prints:

```
The Wolf of Wall Street, The Shawshank Redemption 49
Pulp Fiction, The Shawshank Redemption, Gone Girl 49
The Lion King, The Wolf of Wall Street, Gone Girl 49
Reservoir Dogs, Django Unchained, The Dark Knight 49
The Wolf of Wall Street, The Godfather, Gone Girl 49
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `combinations` which is the perfect tool for this. You can simplify everything to a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combo(l):
    result = sorted([", ".join(y) for i in range(len(l)) for y in combinations(l,i) if len(", ".join(y))<50],
                    key=lambda s: len(s), reverse=True)
    for i in result[:5]: #get the best 5 result only
        print (i, len(i))

combo(films)

#The Wolf of Wall Street, The Shawshank Redemption 49
#Pulp Fiction, The Shawshank Redemption, Gone Girl 49
#The Lion King, The Wolf of Wall Street, Gone Girl 49
#Reservoir Dogs, Django Unchained, The Dark Knight 49
#The Wolf of Wall Street, The Godfather, Gone Girl 49
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it (basically it is like my solution).  The only aspect I find problematic is that your outer loop continues when the inner one didn't yield anything anymore.  So you also check for five-movie combinations when the four-movie combinations all were too long already.

Comment: Maybe someone didn't like the variable name `l` which looks like `1` in many fonts and therefore should never be used IMHO.  Or the other one-letter variables which make the code hard to understand.  Or the long line was disliked.  Or printing instead of returning/yielding the results.  But that's guesswork.  I mostly like your solution.

Comment: Yeah I just want to make sure it's a correct answer or if not I'll fix it. Otherwise I have to delete it even it's actually valid.

Comment: This solution also tries all combination with five movie names, even if all combinations with four movie names were too long already. This is no problem in this case but it sure will be a massive (and easily avoidable) problem if you have a longer list of movies. With a thousand movies this solution will not terminate within a reasonable time.